# Waking up a killed app using didEnterRegion and then scanning for iBeacon

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

My project consist to have one iBeacon for each room of a house. 
When the user get in in the house, my app perform a scan process to detect what iBeacon's is seen in real-time(UUID, Major and Minor) and what's iBeacon has the strongest RSSI signal. If the strongest signal is the same for 10sec, so my app know in what room the user is and show it as a notification.

I need to perform this process during background mode even the iPhone is locked or the app is killed.

Using didEnterRegion, I can wake up my app for few seconds to perform an action.
However, my scan process (which I described above) must be hold more than few seconds but less than < 3minutes (time to user to go to a room and stay) with scan interval of 1second or 2 second

Is-it a way to perform what I want to do with CoreBluetooth Scan ?
CoreLocation can't give me RSSI signal to do a filtering process, is it right ?

Thanks you,

Greg

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you want with CoreBluetooth by turning on ranging at the same time as monitoring.  This will give you a RSSI reading for each visible beacon once per second, for up to 3 minutes after first detection.  See here for details:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

CoreBluetooth will not help you because it does not let you detect iBeacons -- Apple blocks this usage.

Comment: "CoreBluetooth will not help you" Are you speaking about CoreLocatlion ?

Comment: After end of 3 minutes monitoring, is it possible to turn it again for 3minutes more ?

Comment: No, I mean CoreBluetooth cannot detect an iBeacon advertisement. Only CoreLocation can on iOS.  And after three minutes of ranging in the background, you cannot turn it on again until one of the following happens:  (1) your app is brought to the foreground, (2) you get a monitoring entry callback for a CLBeaconRegion (3) you get a monitoring exit callback for a CLBeaconRegion.

Comment: @davidyoung When you're speaking about entry callback for a CLBeaconRegion. Beacons are defined by UUID, Major and Minor. Does it means iOS I can monitor 3 minutes again because other Major or Minor is discovered ? Or it has to be a new UUID ?

Comment: It can be any  CLBeaconRegion.  If you set up a region with UUID/major/minor, and go in or out of it, the 3-minute clock starts again.

Comment: @davidyoung Thanks. However, I would define CLBeaconRegion by different UUID only. Is it problem for Apple App Review if use different UUID for different level of my house ? Not Major. Because regarding apple doc "A proximity UUID (universally unique identifier), which is a 128-bit value that uniquely identifies one or more beacons as a certain type or from a certain organization" Apple specify that UUID is use for certain organization or type.

Comment: Don't worry about restrictions on how you use a Proximity UUID.  Apple makes no such restrictions.  The statement about one per organization is meant to express a typical best practice for most use cases.  Other use cases require more Proximity UUIDs, and Apple allows your app to monitor for up to 20 different ones  at the same time.  I have several apps in the AppStore that do this.